# Install Foundation 6 Sass in existing project folder

Tags: git, zurb-foundation-6

I have an existing project folder tracked by Git. I want to install Foundation 6 using `foundation new` (command line interface) into my existing project folder `mystic`. Is this possible? Because when I do `foundation new` its creating a new project folder.

Is it maybe possible to do `foundation new` in a 'temporary' folder (with same name as my existing theme folder and then copy **all** the foundation files from this folder into my theme project folder (with the same name)?

Answer (score 0):

The command `foundation new` creates a completely new project. It *is* possible to run the latter command in a tmp folder then copy files to another.

But an easier way to integrate Foundation 6 in an already existing project is to use any of the package managers listed on their website:

http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/installation.html

For example, you can use `bower install foundation-sites` and that creates a bower_components folder with the Foundation 6 files ready to be included.